# concatenating string and numbers Java

Tags: java

Why is the output different  in these cases ?

`int x=20,y=10;`

`System.out.println("printing: " + x + y);`   ==>     *printing: 2010*

`System.out.println("printing: " + x * y);`   ==>     *printing: 200*

Why isn't the first output 30? Is it related to operator precedence ? Like first "printing" and x are concatenated and then this resulting string and y are concatenated ? Am I correct?

Comment: "printing: " + x converted it to string and then + y is just string concatenation. Where as in x*y  '*' is performed first and hence u ll get 200.

Comment: think you know the answer and yet asked for fun ;)

Comment: @SenthilKumar I wasn't sure of the answer.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Its the `BODMAS` Rule

**I am showing the Order of precedence below from Higher to Low:**

```
B  - Bracket 
O  - Power
DM - Division and Multiplication
AS - Addition and Substraction
```

**This works from** `Left to Right` **if the Operators are of Same precedence**

Now

`System.out.println("printing: " + x + y);`

`"printing: "` : Is a String"

`"+"`  : Is the only overloaded operator in Java which will concatenate Number to String.
         As we have 2 "+" operator here, and x+y falls after the `"printing:" +` as already taken place, Its considering x and y as Strings too.

So the output is **2010.**

`System.out.println("printing: " + x * y);`

Here the

`"*"`: Has higher precedence than `+`

So its `x*y` **first** then `printing: +`

So the output is **200**

**Do it like this if you want 200 as output in first case:**

```
System.out.println("printing: "+ (x+y));
```

The **Order of precedence of** `Bracket` is **higher** to `Addition`.

Answer (score 9):

Basic math tells you that adding numbers is done each at a time.

So `"printing: " + x` is computed first. As it s a `string + int` the result is `"printing: 20"`. Then you add `y` so `"printing: 20" + y` equals `"printing: 2010"`.

In the second case, multiplying is prioritary. So first `x * y` is calculated and equals `200`. Then `"printing: " + 200` equals `"printing: 200"`.

Answer (score 4):

The results that you observe are certainly related to operator *precedence* and also the *order of  evaluation*. In the absence of another rule, i.e. an operator of higher precedence, operators are evaluated in order from left to right.

In the first expression, all operators have the same precedence, because they're the same operator: `+`, and so the first operation is evaluated. Since it involves a `String`, it is `String` concatenation, and the result is a `String`; similarly for the following `+`.

In the second expression, one of the operators is `*`, which has higher precedence than `+`, and so is evaluated first. You get the result of the multiplication, an integer, and *then* the concatenation of a `String` and an `int` due to the `+`.

Answer (score 1):

This will print `30`:

```
System.out.println("printing: " + (x + y))
```

You need the parentheses to express the precedence you wish for.

Comment: I know ! But that is not my question .

Comment: It requires nothing more than actually reading the Java operator precedence rules.

Answer (score 1):

***It is for operator precedence***

```
System.out.println("printing: " + x * y);
```

here * operator has more precedence than + so first it calculate `x * y`.

```
System.out.println("printing: " + x + y);
```

Where as here all are same operator and it will be treated as String concatenation operation as there is one `string` value is there.

if you involve bracket into this - System.out.println("printing: " + (x + y));

Then bracket ( operator has more precedence than + so first it will calculate `(x + y)` and will print `30`

[check detail operator precedence order](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html)

Answer (score 0):

In the first printing line, the + operator is applied first between the String and the int and the result is a String which is again concatenated with another int resulting a String.

In the second line, the order of the operations is: first the multiplication and the resulted int concatenated to the String.

Answer (score -1):

`System.out.println("2*("+a"+"+b"*"+c")")`

How to print this