# Does Java implicitly convert int to String when using the "+" operator on int + String operation?

Tags: java

I have the following code:

```
    System.out.println("12" + 34);    // prints "1234"

    System.out.println(1 + 2 + "34"); // prints "334"
```

I was expecting an error, instead, my int values got concatenated to the String without error.

Can someone explain **in detail** what goes on above?

1. Does Java implicitly convert int to String type when it notices an int AND String data type in a "+" operation?
2. Why isn't there an error thrown due to wrong data types when using the + operator?
3. If there were indeed implicit conversion going on, why does Java do that and not throw an error?

Answer (score 2):

This answer addresses your second example:

```
 System.out.println(1 + 2 + "34"); // prints "334"
```

What is happening here is that the expression `1 + 2` is happening *first*, due to the left-to-right precedence of the `+` operator.  Actually, any operator has left to right precedence all other things being of the same precedence.  So, first `1 + 2` evaluates as integer addition to `3`, leaving us with:

```
 System.out.println(3 + "34"); // prints "334"
```

Next, `3 + "34"` evaluates as string concatenation, similar to your first example, printing `"334"`.

Comment: I understand precedence, what i'm asking is

 1. why did java evaluate it as a string concatenation instead of throwing an error? 
 2. did an implicit conversion happen to the int value?

Comment: Java must be, at some point, internally using `toString` on the integer literal.  Anyway, interpreting `+` as string concatentation is the only operation which makes sense, right?

Comment: the following [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47605/string-concatenation-concat-vs-operator) answers my question:

you were right! at some point it uses the toString() method :)

Answer (score 0):

It is java concatenate. please refer the link.

> [concatenating string and numbers Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12028779/concatenating-string-and-numbers-java)